# Passing lat and long to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, maps

I have an iframe map with it's coordinates, and two inputs with values under them and these values come from the database, i want to pass those values to the map coordinates, how can i do that? here is my code:

```html
 <iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+MYLAT+','+MYLONG+'&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

<form>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="Latitude" id="lat">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="Longitude" id="long">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you page is loaded from a php file !?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass attributes directly to the iFrame DOM node, due to security reasons. You need to find other way to pass them to the map. Maybe load the map with the parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeloc()
{
var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
var long = document.getElementById('long').value;
var src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+lat+","+long+"&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed";
document.getElementById('map').src = src;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" id="map" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='+MYLAT+','+MYLONG+'&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

<form>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="Latitude" id="lat">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="Longitude" id="long">
</div>
</form>
<button onclick='changeloc();'>Change loc</button>
```

Try this i added a botton that change the src of the iframe

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: because you'r runing it in stackoverflow, copy the url generated in the snippet

Comment: Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: do you load the page from a php script

Comment: there is an outher way of doing that, did you try using [google map javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)

Comment: i did but i don't want something with api's because i have multiple maps with multiple api's which causes a conflict, that's why im using iframe maps

Comment: if write a clean code it would be no conflict, because the iframe had security problem